# Compiled Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I just found this out and I'm hoping someone has a clue as to what's going on. Commands to follow (run this in a temp directory, clearing everything beforehand):

No problems:

```
cat << EOF > Myface.java
public interface Myface {}
EOF

cat << EOF > Myclass.java
public class Myclass implements Myface {}
EOF

javac Myface.java
javac Myclass.java
```

Myclass won't compile:

```
cat << EOF > Myface.java
package Mypackage;
public interface Myface {}
EOF

cat << EOF > Myclass.java
package Mypackage;
public class Myclass implements Myface {}
EOF

javac Myface.java
javac Myclass.java
```

Myclass WON'T compile:

```
cat << EOF > Myface.java
package Mypackage;
public interface Myface {}
EOF

cat << EOF > Myclass.java
package Mypackage;
public class Myclass implements Myface {}
EOF

javac Myclass.java
```

What's going on here?

EDIT: All the commands, run:

```
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ ls
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/javatest
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myface.java
> public interface Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myclass.java
> public class Myclass implements Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ javac Myface.java
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ javac Myclass.java
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ ls
Myclass.class  Myclass.java  Myface.class  Myface.java
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ rm *
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myface.java
> package Mypackage;
> public interface Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myclass.java
> package Mypackage;
> public class Myclass implements Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ javac Myface.java
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ javac Myclass.java
Myclass.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Myface
public class Myclass implements Myface {}
                                ^
1 error
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ rm *
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myface.java
> package Mypackage;
> public interface Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ cat << EOF > Myclass.java
> package Mypackage;
> public class Myclass implements Myface {}
> EOF
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ 
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$ javac Myclass.java
Myclass.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Myface
public class Myclass implements Myface {}
                                ^
1 error
javatest@l-bel-smai-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Can you show the commands you ran, the folders you ran them from, and the error messages that were output by the compiler?

Comment: Java/Class files must be put in the class path in a subfolder structure according to their packages. Maybe thats the problem here.

Comment: Geez, what a long day. You're right Gandalf. Write it in an answer and claim your prize ;).

Comment: There is no requirement in Java that the source files be in any particular directory structure (some tools may depend on it, but none in the JDK do that I am aware of).  It is sane to put them in a directory structure of course :-)

Comment: @TofuBeer That's just not so. The structure of a JAR file is completely specified, and 'loose' .class files lying around a file system are expected to conform to the same directory structure. Otherwise classpath searches won't work, which is why the failing cases here are failing.

Comment: Source files do not go in a JAR.  I didn't say anything about class files.

Comment: @TofuBeer fair enough, but the compiler is a tool in the JDK, and it is documented thus: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html: "If packages are used, the local path name within the directory or archive must reflect the package name." And this question proves that it is only looking in certain places for source files.

Comment: From that same tech note: "You should arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package tree".  If you rely on the compiler to find the source files then, yes, you need to have the package and directory match.  If you pass all of the files that need to be compiled on the command line (say *.java) then it doesn't matter what the packages are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah here we go:
Java/Class file directory structure must match the package structure the Java classes are declared in for compilation and class loading to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While compiling Myclass.java add the classpath option

```
javac -classpath . Myclass.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 2: When you compile `Myclass.java` the `javac` will look for `Mypackage/Myface.class`. Thats not there. You should compile with `javac -d .` which makes `javac` to create the appropriate directory structure for classes it generates. That is also implicitely in the searchpath for the next `javac` call.

Case 3: When you compile `Myclass.java` it will look for `Mypackage/Myface.class`, then for a suitable source file given on the commandline then for a suitable sourcefile in `Mypackage/Myface.java`. Neither exist. Either compile with `javac -d Myface.java Myclass.java` or shove the `*.java` into the appropriate directory structure indicated by the package names.